# ListPointPlot3D {{x1,y1,z1},...} with Manipulate t. Data is {{t1,x1,y1,z1},{t2,x2,y2,z2}...}

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a data {{t1,x1,y1,z1},{t2,x2,y2,z2}...}, and I am trying to plot 'x,y,z' in 3D with Manipulating 't'

I have tried the similar thing before, but the 'x,y,z' were a function of t. (I wrote it down at the bottom of this article.)

My question is, how do I modify this code to plot 'x,y,z' data in 3D while Manipulating 't'?

```
r = 0.1;T=4.2738;a=1.4073;h=-0.0152867;
Manipulate[{x, y, z} = {r*Cos[(2 Pi/T)*t + a], 
   r*Sin[(2 Pi/T)*t + a], h}; 
 ListPointPlot3D[{{x, y, z}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}}], {{t, 0, "t"},
   0, 15.54, 0.035}]
```

I also tried to {x, y, z} = {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@ data;,...} , but it didn't work. ;(

Comment: Do you want to show a single point `{x,y,z}` as a function of the slider position `t`? Or do you want to plot a list of many points, each with an expression depending on `t`? I am asking because the example seems to imply the former, but the text the latter

Comment: yes, that's what I want. 
sry for example...It was just to show how I tried but it was not helpful...
I tried that code by changing the part of {x, y, z} =~~~to  {x, y, z} = {#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@ data;,...} but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second attempt. We have 4d data. The first element of each datum is a time value. The rest of the elements of each datum represent x,y,z coordinates. We want a manipulate that shows a point corresponding to the coordinates for each t as we iterate through the t. I assume `rawData` is defined to be your 4d data.

```
structuredData = {First@#, Rest@#} & /@ rawData;
timeFn = Interpolation[structuredData];
Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
    Point[timeFn[t]], 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}}],
  {{t, 0, "t"}, 0, 15.54, 0.035}]
```

The interpolation probably isn't strictly necessary, but I didn't want to deal with the edge cases and I don't know much about your context. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: I love you. 
I should have removed time data first

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is an answer, but maybe it will trigger you to clarify your question. First, organize your code into functions:

```
aPoint[r_, T_, a_, h_][t_] := {r*Cos[(2 Pi/T)*t + a], r*Sin[(2 Pi/T)*t + a], h};
plotFn = aPoint[0.1, 4.2738, 1.4073, -0.0152867];
```

Now, I'm not sure what `Manipulate` is giving you here, because you can just use `ListPointPlot3D` directly on a set of data:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
  Table[plotFn[t], {t, 0, 15.54, .035}],
  PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}}]
```

[image]

Now, I'm not sure if that's correct, I'm just plugging in what you provided. I suppose what `Manipulate` could provide is a one-point-at-a-time visualization, but you don't need `ListPointPlot3D` in that case:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
    Point[plotFn[t]], 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}}], {{t, 0, "t"},
  0, 15.54, 0.035}]
```

Or maybe even something like the following?

```
Manipulate[
  Animate[
    Graphics3D[
      {PointSize[.05], Point[aPoint[r, T, a, h][t]]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
    {{t, 0, "t"}, 0, 15.54, 0.035}],
  {{r, .1}, .01, 1},
  {{T, 4.2738}, 0, 10},
  {{a, 1.4073}, 0, 2 Pi},
  {{h, -0.0152867}, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: I mean, there is no problem when x[t],y,[t],z[t] and information about 't' are given. However, I need to plot the data {{t1,x1,y1,z1},{t2,x2,y2,z2}...} in 3d, not the function of 't'

Comment: yeah, I don't know what that means. How do you plot 4d data in 3d?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you expect the plot to look like.

Comment: As I said, mabye this "answer" can be more of a trigger to get you to clarify your question.

Comment: For example, if x=t, y=2t, z=3t, and t=1,2,3, then we can use that method. But when the data is given as {{1,0.1,2.2,4.3},{2,2.2,4.6,6.4},{3,3.2,6.7,9.4}}, we cannot use it.

Comment: Oh, so this isn't a question about visualization, it's a question about how to structure your data?

Comment: I have a data {{t1,x1,y1,z1},{t2,x2,y2,z2}...} now, and I need to plot it in 3d by adjusting 't'. 
Think about a point moving with 't'. when the time is 't1', its coordinate will be (x1,y1,z1)
My question is, I want to show its coordinate by adjusting 't'